# Convergence to L

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am not sure how to prove convergence. I think I have to use the $\varepsilon,N$ convergence rule but I am not sure how to manipulate the LHS to this form.

Statement to prove:

> $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $\ell\in\Bbb R$. If for any $\frac{1}{2}<\varepsilon<1$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|a_n-\ell|\le\sqrt{1-\varepsilon}$ whenever $2n>N$, then $(a_n)$ converges to $\ell$.

Comment: Welcome. Try to avoid using pictures and take the time to type up your post with MathJax instead (it's not that hard to learn). You can click: "edit" to see what I've done

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: As for your question, it'd be good if you could expand on what the problem is. I, or many other users, could just give you: "the right answer", but we'd rather help you constructively if you give us some more detail in return